# How do I create a Geodataframe which the data is grouped by User ID & the timestamp is sorted from oldest to most recent?

Tags: geopandas, sorting, grouping, geodataframe

I've been struggling to complete this exercise (Exercise 2 Problem 3) which you guys can refer to this [link](https://github.com/Automating-GIS-processes-II-2023/Exercise-2). **A reminder that the kruger_points.shp is obtained from Exercise 2 Problem 2**. Here's the specific problem that I'm trying to tackle.

[image]

Here's the head of the original dataframe (kruger_points.shp).
[image]

I'm trying to create a new geodataframe which the data is **grouped according to userid** and **the timestamp is sorted from oldest to most recent.** The code is written down below:

```
sorted_test = {"userid": [], "timestamp":[]}

for name, group in grouped_by_users:
    iterate_for_userid = group["userid"].sort_values(ascending = True)
    sorted_test["userid"].append(iterate_for_userid)
    iterate_for_timestamp = group["timestamp"].sort_values(ascending = True)
    sorted_test["timestamp"].append(iterate_for_timestamp)

sorted_df = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(sorted_test)
sorted_df.head()
```

When I checked the new dataframe, I realised that the row contained everything instead of **timestamp** and **userid** only.

[image]

Therefore, what is the proper way to solve this problem?

Comment: Does my answer work?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I'm unable to change the 29-2-2023 because the value is not yet in datetime value. When I tried to convert to datetime, I can't because of the incorrect leap year date.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import LineString, Point

#Create a test df
columns = ["lon", "lat", "userid", "timestamp"]
data = [[12.514, 58.293, 1, '2024-01-19 10:13:25'], [12.623, 58.338, 1, '2024-01-19 10:13:30'], [12.869, 58.312, 1, '2024-01-19 10:13:31'], [12.96, 58.295, 1, '2024-01-19 10:13:32'], [13.05, 58.266, 1, '2024-01-19 10:13:34'], [13.106, 58.238, 1, '2024-01-19 10:13:36'], [13.237, 58.211, 1, '2024-01-19 10:13:38'], [13.348, 58.194, 1, '2024-01-19 10:13:39'], [13.405, 58.179, 1, '2024-01-19 10:13:41'], [13.528, 58.155, 1, '2024-01-19 10:14:49'], [13.59, 58.175, 1, '2024-01-19 10:14:52'], [13.656, 58.216, 1, '2024-01-19 10:14:55'], [13.686, 58.245, 1, '2024-01-19 10:14:58'], [13.72, 58.267, 1, '2024-01-19 10:14:59'], [14.035, 58.634, 2, '2024-01-19 10:15:01'], [13.992, 58.543, 2, '2024-01-19 10:15:03'], [13.979, 58.477, 2, '2024-01-19 10:15:05'], [13.944, 58.441, 2, '2024-01-19 10:15:06'], [13.905, 58.426, 2, '2024-01-19 10:15:08'], [13.871, 58.398, 2, '2024-01-19 10:15:09'], [13.88, 58.381, 2, '2024-01-19 10:15:11'], [14.109, 58.407, 2, '2024-01-19 10:15:14'], [14.203, 58.449, 2, '2024-01-19 10:15:15'], [14.274, 58.453, 2, '2024-01-19 10:15:17'], [14.366, 58.462, 2, '2024-01-19 10:15:18'], [14.445, 58.487, 2, '2024-01-19 10:15:19'], [14.492, 58.53, 2, '2024-01-19 10:15:21'], [14.495, 58.584, 2, '2024-01-19 10:15:23'], [14.533, 58.633, 2, '2024-01-19 10:15:25'], [14.553, 58.653, 2, '2024-01-19 10:15:26'], [13.74, 57.974, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:28'], [13.652, 57.967, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:29'], [13.593, 58.007, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:31'], [13.574, 58.017, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:33'], [13.553, 57.998, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:34'], [13.537, 57.994, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:35'], [13.459, 57.993, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:37'], [13.408, 57.991, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:39'], [13.352, 58.01, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:41'], [13.366, 58.064, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:42'], [13.407, 58.089, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:43'], [13.453, 58.108, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:45'], [13.425, 58.136, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:46'], [13.363, 58.138, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:47'], [13.286, 58.12, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:50'], [13.212, 58.112, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:52'], [13.132, 58.098, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:53'], [13.078, 58.069, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:55'], [13.056, 58.068, 3, '2024-01-19 10:15:55']]
df = pd.DataFrame().from_records(data=data, columns=columns)
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
df = df.sample(frac=1) #shuffle the rows
df["geometry"] = df.apply(lambda x: Point(x["lon"], x["lat"]), axis=1) #Create a point geometry column

#Sort by userid and timestamp:
sorted_frame = df.sort_values(by=["userid","timestamp"], ascending=[True, False])
#print(sorted_frame.head())
#        lon     lat  userid           timestamp               geometry
# 13  13.720  58.267       1 2024-01-19 10:14:59   POINT (13.72 58.267)
# 12  13.686  58.245       1 2024-01-19 10:14:58  POINT (13.686 58.245)
# 11  13.656  58.216       1 2024-01-19 10:14:55  POINT (13.656 58.216)
# 10  13.590  58.175       1 2024-01-19 10:14:52   POINT (13.59 58.175)
# 9   13.528  58.155       1 2024-01-19 10:14:49  POINT (13.528 58.155)

#groupby userid and pass the points of each user to LineString
linedf = sorted_frame.groupby("userid", as_index=False).agg({"geometry": lambda x: LineString(x)})
linedf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(data=linedf, geometry=linedf.geometry, crs=4326)
linedf.plot(figsize=(10,10), column="userid", cmap="cool")
```

[image]

Comment: Encountered this error when trying to convert to datetime: "ParserError: day is out of range for month: 2015-02-29 13:08" Furthermore, why my code that involved for loop didn't work?

Comment: 2015-02-29 doesnt exist, 2015 wasnt a leap year